# Create product clustering based on customer views

Tags: neo4j, cluster-analysis, spherical-kmeans

I have 1 million rows like this:

customer_id  product_id_viewed
12345   [756436, 369955, 1244356, 4689667]

I want to cluster the products that are typically viewed together into separate clusters based on an aggregate of the customers viewing patterns.  How do I do that?

Another step I've taken is to load this data into Elasticsearch and perform significant_terms query against the customer views using each of one my product_ids. I then get back 10 products for every product that are most likely to be viewed together, along with a score.  My ultimate desire is to be able to cluster this product data in a way that delineates different "personality" types or interests.

Would a graph DB like neo4j be able to help here or some other clustering algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

Clustering is the wrong approach.

There is no reason to assume that these patterns are disjoint and that a total parting is appropriate.

Instead do **market basket analysis** aka **frequent itemset mining**.

Comment: Anony-Mousse, that is not the final result I am looking for.  The Elasticsearch query already gives me that. Like I said, what I am looking to do is separate the products into separate clusters based on the an aggregate of all the customers viewing patterns.

Comment: FIM is much closer to clustering than to that similarly search you did with ES. It is based on aggregating the customer viewing patterns ("frequent" here literally is "frequently viewed together"). With naive partitioning you run into trouble: what about products that were never viewed together with others? Where would you "cluster" them?